# Add HTML markup to materialize.css tooltip

Tags: css, materialize

Is there a way to add HTML markup to the tooltip in materialize? I'm trying to arrange some data as definition list  inside a tooltip. I tried to add it directly into the data-tooltip attribute but it doesn't seem to recognize the tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In materialize.js, around line 1258 make the following change to covert all tooltips to html.

```js
// Change .text()
newTooltip.children('span').text(origin.attr('data-tooltip'));
// To .html()
newTooltip.children('span').html(origin.attr('data-tooltip'));
```

Comment: ^^^ If I knew your address I'd send a fruit basket for this

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version you can use:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50, tooltip: 'some text', html: true});
  });
```

See http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html

Comment: TIP: I also had to override the default .material-tooltip style in order to support line breaks, i.e. `.material-tooltip { white-space: pre-wrap; }`

Answer (score 5):

In Materialize v0.100.2 is possible to use **data-html** attribute.
If is set data-html="true", then Materialize renders as $(...).html()

So this will be rendered as $(...).text()

```
<a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">Hover me!</a>
```

And this as $(...).html()

```
<a class="btn tooltipped" data-html="true" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">Hover me!</a>
```

Comment: doesn't work in v1.1.0 :(